# ALTER USER IDENTIFIED BY

Tags: sql, oracle, passwords

I have more users that have account_status expired under dba-users.
I want to change all password for my users with the same password.
How can create a script for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is a very bad idea do have multiple users with the same known password, you'd simply use sql to write sql:

```
spool my_security_risk.sql
select 'alter user '||
        username ||
        ' identified by "security_risk_password";'
from dba_users
where account_status='EXPIRED';
spool off
```

What you propose would be a terminating offense at most places I've worked. May I ask why you want to do this? Perhaps some of those accounts should be dropped. Perhaps some should locked.  Perhaps they should just be left alone, to be reset by the user the next time they connect.  At this point I fear you are trying to solve a non-existent problem.  You might gain some more insight by reading [this](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/exploring-password-lifetime-and-grace-period/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply first
it is a new database which is not currently being used. This procedure is used exclusively for testing

Comment: _"new database which is not currently being used"_   All the more reason to consider WHY a given account is expired, rather than blindly un-expiring them.

Comment: Yes, the consideration is right.
a db-copy was made from a database in use, on this new one.
Before making it operational, the customer wants to run tests and has asked us to proceed like this

Comment: "a db-copy was made from a database in use, on this new one"  That misses the point of my "why" question.  You then need to consider why they are locked on the source.  If you need to unlock them for testing, you are probably creating an invalid test environment.

Comment: I don't know why they are stuck at the source.
it is a request that comes from the supplier.
Your support, however, is very useful to clarify these points

Comment: _"it is a request that comes from the supplier"_   So _talk_ to them.  _Explain_ the possible problems.  Ask _them_ the same questions we've been asking you. A good DBA doesn't just roll over for every hare-brained "requirement" sent their way.